# Clip inside clip created by AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, clip, addchild

There are two clips:*main_mc* and *child_mc*. The *main_mc* is on main-timeline of stage. The *child_mc* is inside *main_mc*, and is created by AS3 code:

```
var child_mc:Sprite=new Sprite;
child_mc.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
child_mc.graphics.drawCircle(15,20,10);
addChild(child_mc);
```

How to change, for example x,y , in *child_mc*, by AS3 created on main-timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a var inside a timeline, it becomes a property of that MovieClip, so you can access it like any other property

So, on the main timeline, you can do the following:

```
main_mc.child_mc.x = 100; 
main_mc.child_mc.y = 100;
```

If I'm misunderstanding, and you want the other direction, you use the `root` or `parent` keywords:

So, from within `main_mc`, you can access the main timeline like so:

```
MovieClip(parent)
```

So if you had another object on the main timeline called `myClip`, and you wanted to hide it with code inside of `main_mc`, you could do:

```
MovieClip(parent).myClip.visible = false;
```

Or, from anywhere:

```
MovieClip(root).myClip.visible = false;
```

---

**EDIT**

It would seem from your comment, that you are attempting to access `child_mc` on the same frame of the main timeline where `main_mc` is created.   The problem with this, is that the main timeline code will run before the timeline code of any of it's children. (so `child_mc` isn't created yet when you main timeline code runs).

If you need a way to wait until all children timeline code has run, you can do this as a workaround:

```
//add a listener to wait until the frame is done being constructed.
this.addEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED,frameConstructed);

function frameConstructed(e:Event):void {
    //remove the listener so this function doesn't keep running on subsequent frames
    this.removeEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, frameConstructed);

    //do what you need to here
    trace(main_mc.child_mc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by it dont' work. Please read my question once more. Clip child_mc is created by script inside main_mc and added by script. On my timeline is only main_mc. Inside main_mc is script as in question. When I write main_mc.child_mc.x I have an error, because this clip don't existing yet.

Comment: I did read your question...   It does work, but it assumes you run the code **after** you've created the `child_mc`

Comment: Thanks very much. This is true. Now all right. Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED was needed. Thanks once more.

Comment: Sorry Batman. Where is this gray chceckmark? I'm blind apparently :).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var child_mc:Sprite=new Sprite;
child_mc.name = "myinnerchild";
```

then:

```
var child:Sprite = main_mc.getChildByName("myinnerchild") as Sprite;
```

And voila.

Comment: This no work, because child_mc not existing yet. Please read answer form Batman :)

Answer (score 0):

If "child_mc" is a global variable or you assign it to a variable you can access when you are ready to move it, the code is just...

```
child_mc.x = 100;
```